# Is there a way to debug mvc application code that has been published and hosted on live server that has different URL from visual studio 2015?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

there are some problems appear in my published website on **live server** that not appear in local version that run on the development environment by **IIS express**

Comment: There are tons of differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 If you want to debug on a live server, use Visual Studio remote debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote debugging, you can follow the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019